# Executing Jmeter with Idle Users/threads

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and performance testing , I have below requirement to verify on the tool:

Need to have 300 transaction per second with 400 concurrent users for Rest API service.

Can guidance and approach will help me a lot .

Thanks in advance

Comment: To achieve 300 transactions per second, it is not required to use 400 threads/users. If the REST API is fast enough, you can achieve the throughput with less number of threads. Always go by transactions, not by the number of users/threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To simulate 400 concurrent users just define 400 threads under [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group). You can also set desired test duration under "Scheduler" section:

   [image: JMeter Thread Group 400 users]
2. To set JMeter requests rate to 300 requests per second add [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) to your Test Plan and configure it like:

   - Target Throughput: `18000` (300 requests per second * 60 seconds in minute)
   - Calculate Throughput based on: `all active threads`

     [image: JMeter Constant Throughput Timer]

     Be aware that Constant Throughput Timer is only capable of **pausing** threads to **limit** JMeter requests rate to defined value, it won't kick off any extra threads to increase the load so actual throughput might be less than you define, it mostly depends on your REST API endpoint response time
3. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to send the request you need to simulate. You may also need a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send i.e. [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) and other headers. See [REST API Load Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-load-testing-how-to-do-it-right) article for details.